# What's the difference between lists constructed by quote and those constructed by cons in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

```
(define ls1 '((1 . 2) 1 . 2))
(set-car! (car ls1) 6)
ls1
(define ls2 (cons '(1 . 2) '(1 . 2)))
(set-car! (car ls2) 6)
ls2
```

After `set-car!`ing, ls1 will be `((6 . 2) 1 . 2)` and ls2 `((6 . 2) 6 . 2)`. It seems that `ls1` and `ls2` have different storage model, and what does it mean when someone says `x is bound to a list`? is x stand for a `starting address` or `location` like that a is the starting address of a[10] in C?

Comment: You're observing that your lisp environment is using structure sharing for identical literals. Modifying them is probably undefined behaviour; look up your language reference for whether it guarantees anything at all for such code.

Comment: @KilianFoth Indeed, I get different results in Larceny and Racket with the same codes. It seems that Larceny uses structure shareing for identical literals, but Racket doesn't ...

Comment: @TimothyLi As I mentioned in my comment in the answer, try running this: `(let* ((ohai (cons 'o 'hai)) (quoted (eval \`(quote ,ohai) (interaction-environment)))) (eq? ohai quoted))`. If it returns true for your implementation, it definitely shares structures. If it returns false, maybe it does some copying first.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Yeah, your code can tell whether they are sharing a common data structure. After looking up a book on the implementation of Scheme, I can understand this question in a low-level way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Quote

Quote returns data which you should *not* modify, and which *may* share structure between themselves.
E.g. if you have a file which contains

```
(define l1 '(1 2 3))
(define l2 '(4 2 3))
```

then the compiler is permitted to allocate `l1` and `l2` in a way that they share their common tail `(cdr l1)` and `(cdr l2`) and/or in the read-only memory.

Modification of such lists is *undefined behavior*.
Do *not* do it.

## `list`

`list` and `cons` create *fresh* objects (different from everything which already exist), they allocate and populate memory. You own them - you can modify them as much as you want.

## Your case

*Both* your `set-car!` calls are *wrong* - you are modifying read-only data and thus triggering *undefined behavior* (i.e., you are lucky your computer did not blow up in your face :-).

Specifically, in the first case, `ls1`, you get what you would get if you did the right thing, i.e.,

```
(define ls1
  (cons (cons 1 2)
        (cons 1 2)))
```

while in the second case the implementation allocated only *one* cons cell `(1 . 2)` and re-used it in creating `ls2`, i.e., you see what you would see if you evaluate the following (legal) code:

```
(define ls2
  (let ((l (cons 1 2)))
    (cons l l)))
```

If there were [*print-circle* in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848310/is-there-an-equivalent-of-common-lisps-print-circle-in-scheme), you could see the data re-use:

```
[1]> (let ((l (cons 1 2)))
        (cons l l)) 
((1 . 2) 1 . 2)
[2]> (setq *print-circle* t)
T
[3]> (let ((l (cons 1 2)))
        (cons l l)) 
(#1=(1 . 2) . #1#)
```

## Binding

*`x` is bound to a value* means that the name `x` refers to the object, the same way in all languages.

The difference in Lisp/Scheme is what the object is.

Here it is the first cons cell of the list - as you have probably [seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) many times, a (linked) list is a chain of cons cell, where `car` contains the value and `cdr` contains the next cons cell in the list.

Comment: Technically, `quote` doesn't create anything. It simply "returns" (as much as such a concept applies to special forms) the datum that was created at read-time. For example, in some Scheme implementations (such as Guile), this expression returns true: `(let* ((ohai (cons 'o 'hai)) (quoted (eval \`(quote ,ohai) (interaction-environment)))) (eq? ohai quoted))`